Conjecture on odd numbers producing (semi) primes
While playing around with numbers, I noticed the following pattern: the sum of two consecutive odd numbers added with the product of said numbers produce a prime or a semi-prime. That is, for any two consecutive odd numbers $a$ and $b$, $a + b + ab$ is either a prime or semi-prime (phrased differently, $4n^2 +4n-1$ always gives a prime or semi-prime for $n \in \mathbb{N}$).
Below are some examples:
3+5+3*5=23 (prime)
5+7+5*7=47 (prime)
7+9+7*9=79 (prime)
9+11+9*11=119(semi-prime, 7 factors 119)
11+13+11*13=167 (prime)
...
I have checked up to the pairs 19 and 21, which is prime. Thus this conjecture seems to be true. Is there any way to prove (or disprove) this conjecture?

What is a semi-prime?

@user2661923 product of two primes

$4n^2+4n−1$ at $n=606$ gives $1471367=17\cdot 41\cdot 2111$ which is neither a prime nor a semiprime.

It can't be a multiple of $2,3$ or $5$ so there's not enough room yet for more than two primes.  Keep going for larger $n$, or try to explain why what I said is true.

$~4n^2 + 4n - 1 = (2n+1)^2 - 2.~$  If $~n \equiv 1 \pmod{7},~$ then $~(2n+1)^2 - 2\equiv {3^2 - 2} \equiv 7 \pmod{7}.~$ So, one approach to looking for counter examples is to manually try $~n \in {8, 22, 36, 50, \cdots }.~$ Then, $~n = 22~$ gives $~45^2 - 2 = 2023 = 7 \times 17^2.$

Also $n=19$ gives $4n^2+4n-1=1519=7^2!!\cdot!31$ which is neither a prime nor a semiprime.

Let's expand the following expression:
Two consecutive odd numbers can be written in the form of
$(2n+1)$ and $(2n+3)$
According to our question
$(2n+1)$+$(2n+3)$+$(2n+1)$$(2n+3)$
=$(4n+4)$+$(4n²+8n+3)$
=$(4n²+12n+7)$
$$f(n)= 4n²+12n+7$$
The conjecture states that this function produces a prime or a semiprime.
We can disprove this conjecture only using one counter example.
As mentioned in the comments.
$$f(18)= 1296+216+7$$
$$f(18)= 1519$$
Which is neither a prime nor a semiprime.
This example contradicts our statement,hence disproves our statement.
Reference for semiprimes:https://prime-numbers.info/list/first-1000-semiprimes
